# What does grep ^- mean in UNIX?

Tags: unix, metacharacters

As title says, what does grep ^- mean in UNIX?
I know what grep is but not the metacharater ^- part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is the regular expression meta character for start of line
`-` in this context is not a metacharacter

This expression therefore matches any - character at the start of a line and with grep will return any line starting with -

will match

```
-Hello world
```

Won't match

```
Hello - world
```

Answer (score 1):

It means to search for a string starting with the hyphen character.

The ^ character matches the beginning of the string

Answer (score 1):

It matches the beginning of a line or string. Please check the list of meta characters supported by different Linux programs here - http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/lnut/ch09_02.htm

Hope this helps.